# HTML 5 video - doesn't work on Safari

Tags: html, video, range

There are many issues about this problem but they were not helpful for me.

Video doesn't work on Safari, but not for all videos. 
I have one video that works after downloading.
Trying to found differences, I have found that in request headers of video that works stays such thing:

```
Range: bytes=0-1
```

But video that works sends other information

```
Range: bytes=0-383630
```

I don't really understand why all videos except one reqest only 1byte  of information. Or my be problem is not in that thing.
All videos are mp4 format.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the problem with Metada in file. There was wrong value about file types. So solution is to convert correctly the file  and set brand to mp42 using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 2 -b:a 128k -vcodec libx264 -brand mp42 -preset slow -f mp4 OUTPUT
```